# Can't create LOV from DataSet in Spagobi Server 5.1

Tags: dataset, spagobi, lov

I'm using Spagobi server 5.1.

When I try to create a Lov from Dataset I always get the error message "An error has occurred. Retry later. If the problems persists, contact the system administrator".

The DataSet creation works fine and also I can see the preview.

Anyone can help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1.Some where you define the wrong information in dataset.
2.Can you send me your full description in SpagoBI Server So, that i can help you further.
3. And in lov management limited rows can be displayed only.

Thanks
Aman Agrawal

Comment: Actually Dataset creation is fine and it returns just three rows. When I try to create LOV I select the Dataset created and clicking on the Test button it gives that error. What do you mean for full description? What do you need?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove underscore symbol from dataset (query), try this again.
2. Can you show me your query.

Thanks
Aman

Comment: Finally I solved it. There is an error in DatasetDetail.class in sbi-dao.jar. In loadFromXML method you should change dataDefinition.substring(startInd + 6, endId); in dataDefinition.substring(startInd + 4, endId); and also dataDefinition.substring(0, startInd+6) in dataDefinition.substring(0, startInd+4)